# Google unable to enable billing due to project limit however there are not any projects with billing enabled

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, project, quota

As you can see in the picture below all of my projects have `billing is disabled`. However when I try to enable billing on one of the projects, I get `Unable to enable billing` popup due to `You have reached the limit of projects on which you can enable billing`. I cannot understand why this is happening because there is not a single project that has billing enabled.
[image]

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its about billing OP should contact google support  https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231?hl=en

Comment: It was free tier project? Are your payment methods are up to date? Is there nothing wrong with your payments? You've created projects at the same time or there was some time differences between them?

Comment: Yes. It is a free tier project. I even deleted all other projects but still I get the same message. When I go the settings for the billing , there are not any project linked at all. I ended up creating a new billing account with the same bank card as the old billing account and linked the new billing account with no problem. Still don't get what was wrong with my previous billing account.

Comment: So you've removed all projects and billing account. When you've created new billing account it worked normally. You didn't reach 300$ or 90 days of free account limit?

Comment: I haven't deleted my old billing account. I didn't knew about the 90 days free account limit. Maybe that is why the old billing account cannot be linked to any projects.

Comment: If you were using a free account, after 90 days or reaching 300$ you will finish free trial account and need to go to paid account. This behavior occurred for more than 24h hours or less?

Comment: It has been like that for more than 24 hours.

Answer (score 5):

Posting this `Community Wiki` for better visibility.

`Re-enable billing on a project` is well described in the [GCP documentation](https://cloud.google.com/billing/docs/how-to/modify-project#to_re-enable_billing_on_a_project_do_the_following), however in this issue OP got an error message that `You have reached the limit of projects on which you can enable billing`. In general, users should file a report to GCP to increase this quota, which is described [here](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/6330231?hl=en).

Main issue in this case is that all OP's projects were disabled and cannot re-enabled it in any project. This might be caused by reaching `Free Account` limits (90 days or 300$) or temporary card issues. Free accounts have some limitations in comparison to regular accounts. It's quite hard to determine it in Stackoverflow.

The best way would be to create an issue on [Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/) under the `Billing` component to have a deep investigation.

**Solution**

OP created a new `Billing Account` and linked projects to this new account.

> I ended up creating a new billing account with the same bank card as the old billing account and linked the new billing account with no problem.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new billing account and connect to it. You can use the same card details as the previous one

Answer (score 0):

add another account and using billing with new account to change Billing Account inside your projects.